# SQL provisioning on Azure with Bicep fails with timeout error - The resource write operation failed to complete successfully

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-bicep

I have written IaC using bicep to provision a SQL server and a database using the code below.

**deploy_sql.bicep**

```
targetScope = 'subscription'


module createSQL './modules/sql/create-sql.bicep' = {
  name: 'CreateProvisionSQL'
  params:{
    server_name: 'sql-db-app-dev'
    admin_username: 'sqladministrator'
    admin_password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    db_name: 'my_db'
  }
  scope: resourceGroup('my-resource-group')
  dependsOn: [createRG]
}

var myoutput = createSQL.outputs.MyConnectionString
```

**./modules/sql/create-sql.bicep**

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-11-01' = {
  name: 'sql-db-app-dev'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  // kind: 'v12.0'
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: 'administratorLogin'
    administratorLoginPassword: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      principalType: 'Group'
      login: 'myGroup'
      sid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      tenantId: tenant().tenantId
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: false
  }
}
}

resource serverName_sqlDBName 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2020-08-01-preview' = {
  parent: sqlServer
  name: 'sample_db'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    name: 'standard'
    tier: 'standard'
    capacity: 10
  }
  properties: {
    collation: 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS'
  }
}
output MyConnectionString string = '${sqlServer.name}${environment().suffixes.sqlServerHostname},1433;'
```

For the deployment, I am deploying using the command below.

`az deployment group create --name deploy_sql --template-file .\create-sql.bicep --resource-group my-resource-group --output jsonc`

What happens is that the deployment runs for about 30 minutes which is rather unusual, then it will eventually timeout with the error below.

One thing to note is that I am constantly deleting the resource and recreating it again by deleting the resource group and the deployment in Azure.

`{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.\",\r\n        \"details\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"code\": \"Conflict\",\r\n            \"message\": \"{\\r\\n  \\\"status\\\": \\\"Failed\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": {\\r\\n    \\\"code\\\": \\\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"details\\\": [\\r\\n      {\\r\\n        \\\"code\\\": \\\"OperationTimedOut\\\",\\r\\n        \\\"message\\\": \\\"The operation timed out and automatically rolled back. Please retry the operation.\\\"\\r\\n      }\\r\\n    ]\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}`

Comment: You posted 2 of your admin passwords. Best to change them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to deploy sample SQL server and database through bicep template. It got successfully deployed.**

The error you are facing is not able to deploy the resources properly it can be because of you are trying to run create resource group command and deployment group command in a single command ant it may be not able to create proper resources.

**To Deploy Bicep file you can try below code:**

From [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-bicep-quickstart?view=azuresql&tabs=CLI#deploy-the-bicep-file)

```
//first create resource group
az group create --name resourcegrpname --location eastus

//Then create an deployment group and deploy file
az deployment group create --resource-group resourcegrpname --template-file main.bicep --parameters administratorLogin=<admin-login>
```

Also check by changing the resource group location.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]